# Why does Excel now give me already existing name range warning on Copy Sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I've been working on a Microsoft Excel 2007 spreadsheet for several days.  I'm working from a master template like sheet and copying it to a new sheet repeatedly.  Up until today, this was happening with no issues.  However, in the middle of today this suddenly changed and I do not know why.  Now, whenever I try to copy a worksheet I get about ten dialogs, each one with a different name range object (shown below as 'XXXX') and I click yes for each one:

> A formula or sheet you want to move or copy contains the name 'XXXX', which already exists on the destination worksheet. Do you want to use this version of the name?
>
> - To use the name as defined in destination sheet, click Yes.
> - To rename the range referred to in the formula or worksheet, click No, and enter a new name in the Name Conflict dialog box.

The name range objects refer to cells in the sheet.  For example, `E6` is called name range `PRE` on multiple sheets (and has been all along) and some of the formulas refer to `PRE` instead of `$E$6`.  One of the 'XXXX' above is this `PRE`.  These name ranges should only be resolved within the sheet within which they appear.  This was not an issue before despite the same name range existing on multiple sheets before.  I want to keep my name ranges.

What could have changed in my spreadsheet to cause this change in behavior?  I've gone back to prior sheets created this way and now they give the message too when copied.  I tried a different computer and a different user and the same behavior is seen everywhere.  I can only conclude something in the spreadsheet has changed.  What could this be and how can I get back the old behavior whereby I can copy sheets with name ranges and not get any warnings?

Looking in the `Name Manager` I see that the name ranges being complained about show twice, once as scope `Template` and again as scope `Workbook`.  If I delete the scope `Template` ones the warning goes away on copy however, I get a bunch of #REF errors.  If I delete the scope `Workbook` ones, all seems okay and the warnings on copy go away too, so perhaps this is the answer, but I'm nervous about what effect this deletion will have and wonder how the `Workbook` ones came into existence in the first place.

Will it be safe to just delete the `Workbook` name manager scoped entries and how might these have come into existence without my knowing it to begin with?

Comment: Did you ever find out why these Workbook-scope names were appearing? I'm seeing the exact same thing - I can fix it by deleting the Workbook names, but I'd be happier if I knew what caused them.

Comment: No, I just deleted per the answer I gave below.  It would be nice to know why this occurs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the Name Manager and find the named items being complained about and delete all those with scope `Workbook` and the issue with copying sheets goes away and the formulas remain intact.

Comment: This will work, as long as you don't have any hidden names in the workbook. I've just had to clean a colleague's workbook that had over 300 hidden names for good measure! You can only clear out hidden names using VBA (see answers below). The one extra thing I had to filter for was names starting with "_xlfn", which are built-in Excel names and cannot be deleted: you get a 1004 run-time error if you try. `If n.Visible = False And Not (Left(n.Name, 5) = "_xlfn") Then n.Delete` did the job

Answer (score 8):

```
Sub TOOLS_DELETENAMEDRANGE()

  Dim nm As name
  On Error Resume Next

  For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If (MsgBox("Delete name- " & nm.name, vbYesNo) = vbYes) Then  
      nm.Delete
    End If
  Next

  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: This is useless... you can you the Name Manager for that.  What should be the reason for using such a code?

Comment: How can I adapt this to only delete ranges that aren't in the workbook scope?

Comment: There are some hidden name ranges that are unaccessible from the Name Manager, and can only be deleted properly using this code. Thanks a million times for it!

Comment: Thank you for this. 99% of the answers on the Internet make it sound as easy as deleting one or more items in Name Manager but have no mention whatsoever of "What if the name Excel is complaining about ISN'T IN THAT LIST?!" After just putting up with this annoyance for years, this simple little VBA subroutine finally did the trick!

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error, but a warning a conflict exists and offers a choice on what to do

When you copy a range that includes reference to a (typically worksheet scope) named range, and that same name exists on the destination sheet, how is Excel to know which name you want to use in the result?

As to whats changed, I suggest you review all the names in your workbook, especially for scope.
Name Manager - `Ctrl-F3`

Comment: I've updated the question to use the word 'warning' instead of 'error', but my question remains.

Answer (score 1):

These names are mostly the result of a data download through a third-party API. The APIs typically use those names as placeholders for cell referencing.

Once you have processed some data, these names are mostly left behind as a general user does not clean up the hidden (or very-hidden) sheets. The difficulty associated with these names is that they also do not show up in the NAMES box and therefore cannot be deleted through that option.

One way that I go about it is to program it through a VBA script. Sample below

```
Sub do_loop_names()
Dim vJunkName As Name
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Names.Count


For Each vJunkName In ThisWorkbook.Names
    vJunkName.Delete
Next vJunkName
End Sub
```

Do note this script will delete ALL names from the workbook, so if there are certain defined names you'd like to keep, please put in the exceptions in the code.

If someone has a more efficient solution, please let me know.

Comment: I know hidden sheets. But what are *very* hidden sheets?

Comment: @nixda You can hide or unhide sheets by right clicking on the sheet tabs as you know. You can do the same thing through VBA, and through VBA you have another option to make sheets very hidden which means they are not available to unhide when right clicking on the sheet tabs.

Comment: @Levi gave a good explanation. very hidden sheets are invisible on the workbook unless set visible through VBA. Hidden sheets can be viewed through the spreadsheet Hide / Unhide option but the _veryhidden_ feature makes these sheets inaccessible unless through VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with 27 mystery named ranges.  I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (as recommended in another answer) to view the list of named ranges (which I had never set up!).  There were many since I had been copying the worksheet tab many times and just clicking "yes" to work around the message.  I highlighted and deleted all the named ranges (one little screen at a time, couldn't Select All).  The next time I tried to copy the worksheet, the copy succeeded without the warning message.

Be sure to copy your original file before trying this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and tried each solution provided, with varying success:

1) I opened the Names Manager and, sure enough, there were a bunch of Names I never created; however, they were NOT the names I was being warned about.  I deleted them anyway to get rid of the clutter, but that wasn't the solution.

2) I tried the code provided by Viquar (start "Sub do_loops_names").  I think part of the code was missed, because I can't see how it actually does anything and, sure enough, nothing happened.

3) I tried the code provided by user345338 (starts with "Sub TOOLS_...") - **PERFECT**.  It walked me through all the hidden names that somehow were stuck in the workbook and deleted them.  Thank you very much, user345338 (whoever you are!).

BTW, to "codea" - user345338's code is not "useless" as it resolved my issue.